# show multiple sprites using one css class, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, sprite

So this is my current code setup that has a block move around and shoot a bullet when the space bar is pressed:

```
var MoveRate = 3;
var keys = {};
var attackx = 0;
var attacky = 0;
setInterval(loop, 20);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
});


function move() { // defines character movement
    var pos = $('#p1').position();
    for (var i in keys) {
        if (i == 38) { //up
            if (pos.top - 3 >= 0) {
                $('#p1').css('top', pos.top -= MoveRate);
            }
        }
        if (i == 39) { //right
            if (pos.left - 6 <= $('#main_body').width()) {
                $('#p1').css('left', pos.left += MoveRate);
            }
        }
        if (i == 37) { //left
            if (pos.left - 3 >= 0) {
                $('#p1').css('left', pos.left -= MoveRate);
            }
        }
        if (i == 40) { //down
            if (pos.top + 23 <= $('#main_body').height()) {
                $('#p1').css('top', pos.top += MoveRate);
            }
        }
    }
};


function shoot() { // defines bullet origin point
    var attackPos = $('#p1').offset();
    for (var i in keys) {
        if (i == 32 && attacky <= 0) { //spacebar
            $('#attack').css('left', attackPos.left += 0);
            $('#attack').css('top', attackPos.top -= 15);
            attackx = $('#p1').offset().left;
            attacky = $('#p1').offset().top;

        }

    }
};


function updatePositions() { // defines movement of all non character objects (i.e. attacks, npcs, weather)
    $('#attack').css('top', attacky -= 5);
};

function loop() { // updates game data every 20 ms
    move();
    shoot();
    updatePositions();
};
```

In CSS i define the attack sprite as the following:

```
#attack{
    background-color: green;
    width: 3px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So this basically has a block moving around that can shoot a sprite and waits for it to go off screen before allowing to shoot again. I want to make it so that it can shoot another sprite while the other is still traveling and have them both show at the same time. I think I am supposed to change attack to a class but not sure how i would implement the jquery side to it.

Comment: It will be easier, if you make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I put all the code in jsfiddle here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/f4ae29dq/1 I've never used it before and not sure if i got the external resources working right or formatted it right.